# Java version for terminator

Tags: windows, windows-7-x64, terminator

Terminator won't launch when double clicking the desktop icon. I have two versions of java installed in Windows 7. The default is C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_45 but terminator only finds the old 1.5 version. What's the best way to provide an argument for terminator_27.52.6964.amd64.msi so it will launch?

Below is the last error when I run it. The first error has more detail and says "JVM Selection: trying to find a 64 bit jvm.dll ... 1.5 is too old..." but I can't copy and paste it. The below error mentions a unix path, not a windows path, so I am not sure where the log file is located. Interesting that it's trying to use the cygwin-launcher.exe. Some of those paths look badly  built too.

Uncaught exception

An error occurred in Terminator:

Exception RuntimeError: Java failed with #

Please send us the contents of the application log, from /home/userid/.terminator/logs/terminator-5368.log

An idea of what you were doing when Java exited might be useful.

Command line was:
C:/Program Files/software.jessies.org/terminator/Resources/salma-hayek/.generated/amd64_Cygwin/bin/java-launcher -Xmx256m -Dorg.jessies.libraryDirectories=C:\Program Files\software.jessies.org\terminator\Resources\terminator.generated\amd64_Cygwin\lib;C:\Program Files\software.jessies.org\terminator\Resources\salma-hayek.generated\amd64_Cygwin\lib -Dorg.jessies.binaryDirectory=C:\Program Files\software.jessies.org\terminator\Resources\salma-hayek.generated\amd64_Cygwin\bin -Dorg.jessies.terminator.dotDirectory=C:\cygwin64\home\gbowm06.terminator -Dorg.jessies.terminator.logDirectory=C:\cygwin64\home\gbowm06.terminator\logs -Dorg.jessies.terminator.serverPortFileName=C:\cygwin64\home\gbowm06.terminator\terminator-server-port -Dorg.jessies.terminator.optionsFile=C:\cygwin64\home\gbowm06.terminator\options -De.gui.HelpMenu.hasManual=true -De.gui.HelpMenu.supportAddress=terminator-users@googlegroups.com -De.gui.HelpMenu.supportSite=http://groups.google.com/group/terminator-users -Djava.class.path=C:\Program Files\software.jessies.org\terminator\Resources\terminator.generated\classes.jar;C:\Program Files\software.jessies.org\terminator\Resources\terminator.generated\classes;C:\Program Files\software.jessies.org\terminator\Resources\salma-hayek.generated\classes;C:\Program Files\software.jessies.org\terminator\Resources\salma-hayek\lib\jars\AppleJavaExtensions.jar;C:\Program Files\software.jessies.org\terminator\Resources\salma-hayek\lib\jars\swing-worker-1.2.jar -De.util.Log.filename=C:\cygwin64\home\gbowm06.terminator\logs\terminator-5368.log -De.util.Log.applicationName=Terminator -Dorg.jessies.aboutBoxIcon=C:\Program Files\software.jessies.org\terminator\Resources\terminator\lib\terminator-128.png -Dorg.jessies.frameIcon=C:\Program Files\software.jessies.org\terminator\Resources\terminator\lib\terminator-128.png -Dorg.jessies.projectRoot=C:\Program Files\software.jessies.org\terminator\Resources\terminator -Dorg.jessies.supportRoot=C:\Program Files\software.jessies.org\terminator\Resources\salma-hayek -Djava.awt.Window.locationByPlatform=true -Dswing.boldMetal=false -Dsun.java2d.d3d=false terminator/Terminator

```
at C:/Program Files/software.jessies.org/terminator/Resources/salma-hayek/bin/invoke-java.rb:514:in `launch'
at C:/Program Files/software.jessies.org/terminator/Resources/terminator/bin/terminator:97:in `launch0'
at C:/Program Files/software.jessies.org/terminator/Resources/terminator/bin/terminator:21:in `block in launch'
at C:/Program Files/software.jessies.org/terminator/Resources/salma-hayek/bin/show-alert.rb:123:in `call'
at C:/Program Files/software.jessies.org/terminator/Resources/salma-hayek/bin/show-alert.rb:123:in `block in run_in_home_directory'
at C:/Program Files/software.jessies.org/terminator/Resources/salma-hayek/bin/show-alert.rb:121:in `chdir'
at C:/Program Files/software.jessies.org/terminator/Resources/salma-hayek/bin/show-alert.rb:121:in `run_in_home_directory'
at C:/Program Files/software.jessies.org/terminator/Resources/salma-hayek/bin/show-alert.rb:153:in `initialize'
at C:/Program Files/software.jessies.org/terminator/Resources/salma-hayek/bin/show-alert.rb:167:in `new'
at C:/Program Files/software.jessies.org/terminator/Resources/salma-hayek/bin/show-alert.rb:167:in `report_exceptions'
at C:/Program Files/software.jessies.org/terminator/Resources/terminator/bin/terminator:21:in `launch'
at C:/Program Files/software.jessies.org/terminator/Resources/terminator/bin/terminator:218:in `<main>'
```

Package 27.52.6964
Revision 6964 (6964)
Built 2015-03-05T14:37:59-08:00

Please mail this error message to terminator-users@googlegroups.com.
You can copy it to the clipboard with Ctrl-C.
Windows won't let you select the text but Ctrl-C works anyway.

OK

Comment: "Please mail this error message to terminator-users@googlegroups.com."

Comment: interacting with an email list well takes significant time and effort. I just need to pass it a jre path.

Comment: Typing java in the search box for the email list shows a cygwin bug has come back from 2014. My cygwin setup is 2.870. My cygwin dll is version 2.0.2-1.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem wasn't the same bug. it did not work because I didn't have a 64 bit version of java installed. Installing the right java allowed terminator to run. Many thanks to "bad" of the terminator-users email list.

Comment: Mad, bad and user18096, but a hat tip is gracious, whatever the name, thank you sir, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/terminator-users/dCsWHSrwB1U.  What makes this recurrent problem particularly difficult to diagnose is that 32 bit Java reports itself shyly as "Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.71-b15, mixed mode)", where 64 bit Java fesses up to be such with "Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.72-b15, mixed mode)".